# Django Cannot Update User Profile Picture

Tags: python, django, forms, image, model

I have created a custom UserProfile model, and want to allow the user to edit his or her profile's fields. The other fields are editable, but the ImageField is not. I am able to store an uploaded image into my target directory (media/profile_pics), but I'm not sure how to link this to the user who is currently logged in so that he or she can navigate back to the profile page and see the new picture.

The code in my views.py is pretty messy. I'm hoping someone can teach me a better way of doing it because it's hacked together with partial understanding.

**models.py**

```
#custom user profile
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    #if user object has been created, we want to create user profile
    if kwargs['created']:
                                                    #returns the instance of our user object
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])
#connecting to the post_save signal. Pass in a function that should run
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

When the user navigates to the place where they can edit their profile, the view function "edit_profile" is used. Here it is in **views.py**:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=user_profile)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        update_profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=user_profile)

                                            #so we know the user object
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid() and update_profile_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_profile_form.save()

            handle_uploaded_file(request, request.FILES['profile_pic'])

            #return redirect(reverse('userapp:profile'))
            args = {'profile_form': update_profile_form}

            return render(request, 'userapp/profile.html', args)

    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form, 'profile_form': profile_form}
        return render(request, 'userapp/edit_profile.html', args)
```

The following function is used by edit_profile to save the file into my target directory. This was taken from the Django documentation:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(request, f):
    with open(os.getcwd() + "/media/profile_pics/" + f.name, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
   # profile_pic = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('profile_pic','city', 'description',)



class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    #template_name='/something/else'

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password'
            #'profile_pic'
        )
```

I display the following HTML, "edit_profile.html" for the user to update the fields:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Profile {% endblock %}


{% block body %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{  form.as_p }}
            {{ profile_form.as_p }}

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>

        </form>
        <br>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is the user profile HTML. After an update, when the user navigates back to the profile, their newly uploaded picture should display:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Profile {% endblock %}


{% block body %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h2>Profile</h2>
        <p>{{ user }}</p>
        <p>First name: {{ user.first_name }}</p>
        <p>Last name: {{ user.last_name }}</p>
        <p>Email: {{ user.email }}</p>
        <p> City: {{ profile_form.instance.city }}</p>
        <p> Description: {{ profile_form.instance.description }}</p>
        <p>
            {% if profile_form.instance.profile_pic %}
                <img src="{{ profile_form.instance.profile_pic.url}}" border-radius=10px style="width:256px;height:256px;" />
            {% endif %}
        </p>


    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: When you say `profile_pic` is not editable? Is it not showing in your template or you are uploading image but it is not being saved?

Comment: I am uploading an image and it is not being saved @sachitad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass request.FILES in form. See here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to handle the uploaded file with a model, as shown in the middle part of the link you sent? That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ok, so I can get basic uploads working and stored but I don't know how to link this to the user. Could you please look at my edit?

Comment: The way you are doing this now is wrong. You only have to pass request.FILES to the form and save it. `update_profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=user_profile, request.FILES)`  `update_profile_form.save()`. No need for the method `handle_uploaded_file()`

Comment: Ok, how do I handle the python error "positional argument follows keyword argument" that is caused by putting request.FILES after the data= and instance= keywords? Thanks for your patience! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: ah yes. try putting request.FILES first. UserProfileForm(request.FILES, data=request.POST, instance=user_profile)

Comment: Yeah, but when you do that you get "__init__() got multiple values for argument 'data'. I think the issue is that it expects the argument for data to be put in the first position, but you're using a default initializer which sets data=request.POST. Therefore, you're essentially telling it that data=request.FILES (from the positional placement) and data=request.POST (from the explicit statement). How do you work around that?

Comment: I haven't tested this yet but you can do it without 'data=' part. UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user_profile)

Comment: If I do that, then calling the is_valid() function on the return value of that form will give false.

Comment: Any ideas Sandeep?

Comment: not sure what is happening. It should work. try printing the form errors and see if there is actually errors.

Comment: The issue was that the other fields in the form were required, and I wasn't filling them out, so it wouldn't update anything.